# how to fix /home/jitpack/build/commons/src/main/res/layout/ AAPT: warn: generated id 'android:id/icon' for external package 'android'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

/home/jitpack/build/commons/src/main/res/layout/md_preference_custom.xml:14: AAPT: warn: generated id 'android:id/icon' for external package 'android'.

Answer (score 0):

This is a warning and **can be ignored**. In the resource that the warning refers to, the id is declared in this way - `android:id="@+android:id/icon"`, if you change it to `android:id="@android:id/icon"`, then the warning will disappear.

Since this resource is located inside the library, you can try to contact the developers or rebuild it yourself from the source.